# Minimizing application following Windows Show desktop command when modal form is opened

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog, delphi-2009

I have a multiple form application and open one of my forms using ShowModal. Is there a way to minimize the whole application when Show Desktop command in Windows is envoked?

P.S. Delphi 2009, Win 7

My code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     Form2.ShowModal;
end;

end.
```

---

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

DPR:

```
program Project1;

uses
  ExceptionLog,
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: That should happen automatically surely. I know my app behaves fine with show desktop. What's special about yours. An MCVE please.

Comment: Reformulated my question. Had to state that my topmost form is modal.

Comment: Should not matter. I have no such problems. Why no MCVE?

Comment: Added my source code.

Comment: Thanks. For completeness can we see the dpr file. I guess both forms are auto created. Older delphis were weak in this area

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice mcve. I don't have d2009, or even a computer right now. I hope somebody else can help.

Comment: Your MVE (it lacks the 'C' as it's not compilable without dfm files) works fine on Win7 with Delphi XE4.

Comment: I just tried it on D2007 and Win 8.1  It behaves as it should, with or without the button press.  Maybe there is an issue with your windows itself.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another program blocking the show desktop operation.  I've experienced issues before that it can be blocked by one program not minimising resulting in everything after that not being asked to minimise.

Comment: Windows + M was the old way to show the desktop and modal forms open in Delphi applications will stop the application from minimizing. Windows + D is the new way to show the desktop in Windows and even open modal forms behave correctly. Windows + D pressed again will also restore applications with modal forms open.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it on D2007 and Win 8.1  It behaves as it should, with or without the button press.  Maybe there is an issue with your windows itself.  I note that you have **uses ExceptionLog** in the dpr file. - This would be the culprit.

Comment: ExceptionLog is added by Eureka Log utility when it's activated. I disabled it which removed the file from uses but unfortunately the program behaviour did not change.